# Equivalence of definitions for Principal nth root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

I have this exercise that requires me to prove that two definitions are equal. The definitions regard principal nth root of unity and they read:

> Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a commutative ring with $1$, let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 1$, be arbitrarily fixed, and let $ \omega \in \mathcal{R}$. Then $\omega$ is said to be a principal nth root of unity if: 
> (1) $\omega^n = 1$;
> (2) $1 - \omega^k$ is not a zero divisor in $\mathcal{R}$ for all $1 \leq k < n$.

and

> Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a commutative ring with $1$, let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 1$, be arbitrarily fixed, and let $ \omega \in \mathcal{R}$. Then $\omega$ is said to be a principal nth root of unity if:
> (1) $\omega^n = 1$;
> (2) $\sum_{j=o}^{n-1}{\omega^{jk} = 0}$ for all $1 \leq k < n$.

And although first assertion is same in the case of both definitions, I can't seem to be able to notice the relation between the second assertions. Can anyone please point me in the right direction on this matter?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\omega^n=1$ rather than $\omega n=1$?

Comment: Note that in the second definition, you're taking the sum of a (finite) geometric series.  You know how to sum those as long as the resulting denominator is non-zero.  You can't actually take a denominator in this case, but multiplying through by the denominator gets you an equation that does hold in a ring, even if the denominator is not invertible in the ring.

Comment: What @RobertShore is saying, but in equations: $(1-\omega^k)(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \omega^{jk})=1-\omega^n=0$. This shows that your first definition implies the second.

Comment: If $R = \mathbf{F}_p$, then $1 \in R$ is a principal $p$th root of unity in the second definition but not in the first.